# EF core 2.0 cannot run Scaffold-DbContext

Tags: entity-framework

### I'm practicing with "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db",created asp.net web core application,created database,and Installed three packages,but it's error when I run "Scaffold-DbContext..."

```html
PM> Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Blogging;Integrated Security=True" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
The Entity Framework Core Package Manager Console Tools don't support PowerShell version 2.0. Upgrade to PowerShell version 3.0 or higher, restart Visual Studio, and try again.
```

---

### restart vs2017, Still wrong ！

My environment:VS2017 15.5

### PMC version:4.5.0.4685

Blogging.Web.csproj

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```